# haskell error: expected and actual types

Tags: haskell

I am using a research tool written in haskell and I am trying to run the code but lots of errors has emerged most of them due to version changes. But I actually could not understand the type mismatch in haskell, for example in this code:

```
mkProp :: String -> String -> Content i
mkProp n s = (CElem (Elem ( N "property") [(( N "name"),(AttValue [Left n]))] [CString False s]))
```

the error is:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Content i0'
                with actual type `i1 -> Content i1'
    In the return type of a call of `CString'
    Probable cause: `CString' is applied to too few arguments
    In the expression: CString False s
    In the third argument of `Elem', namely `[CString False s]'
```

Can someone please explain to me how to fix errors of this type because I also got the same error in 
different code but the probable cause is because `CElem` is applied to too few arguments?? I mean where to look in the code is it wrong with the type that the function used or the arguments passed?

I am using ghc7.6.3 and HaXml package v. 1.13.3.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's `Content`? What's `CElem`? What's `Elem`?

Comment: You are not using HaXml 1.13.3, otherwise this would probably compile.  For reference, compare the arguments to the `CString` constructor of `Content` in [v1.13.3](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HaXml-1.13.3/docs/Text-XML-HaXml-Types.html#g:3) and the latest [v1.24.2.1](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HaXml-1.24.1/docs/Text-XML-HaXml-Types.html#g:3), notice how there's an extra argument in the later version?  That's what's giving you an error.  In fact, v1.13.3 is the last version on Hackage to have that version of the `CString` constructor.

Comment: Ok, that means Cstring on later version has 3 arguments but when I modified the code from [CString False s] to [CString False s _],it gives me this error: Pattern syntax in expression context: _

Comment: Sorry I have one more question, if I used cabal update does it update the versions I am using, for example the HaXml from 1.13.3 to the latest?

Comment: @user3644664 You could fill the hole with `undefined` (the `_` is a pattern, not an expression), but this wouldn't be a very good solution.  You really should be building with correct version of the HaXml library, otherwise don't expect the program to work correctly even if it does compile.  As for `cabal update`, all it does is fetch an updated list of packages and checks of `cabal-install` has any updates, it does not compile code without `cabal build` or `cabal install`.

Comment: bheklilr thank you very much for your help, it works now.